# How to call a graphql query again with different variable value?

Tags: react-native, apollo

This is my code file.

```
import React from 'react'
import { gql } from 'apollo-boost'
import { Query } from 'react-apollo'

const CATEGORY_QUERY = gql`Some query here`

const handleOnCategoryTouch = (id) => {
  //Again call the query
}

const Home = () => (
  <Query
    query={CATEGORY_QUERY}
    variables={{ limit: 20, cursor: "", idcategory: 0 }}
  >
    {({ loading, error, data }) => {
      if (loading) return <Text>Loading...</Text>;
      if (error) return <Text>Error :(</Text>;
      return (
        <Categories
          categories={data.get_discovery_kol_data.categories}
          content={data.get_discovery_kol_data.postKol}
          onCategoryTouch={handleOnCategoryTouch}
        />
      )
    }}
  </Query>
```

Here `Categories` is a component which renders categories as a chips in UI. On click of that chip, we get the categoryId. Now I want to recall the `CATEGORY_QUERY`, with the latest id and update the existing result, how do it ?

I am using

```
"apollo-boost": "^0.1.3",
"graphql": "^0.13.2",
"react": "^16.3.0-alpha.1",
"react-apollo": "^2.1.0-beta.3",
"react-native": "0.54.2",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best approach would be to create wrapping component

parent.js

```
import Home from './Home'

class Parent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <Home 
      category={this.state.id} 
      onCategoryChanged={(id) => { this.onCategoryChanged(id) }}
    />
  }

  onCategoryChanged (id) {
    this.setState({ id })
  }
}
```

Home.js

```
class Home extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <a onClick={() => { this.props.onCategoryChanged(1) }}>Change category to 1</a>
    )
  }
}

export default graphql(CATEGORY_QUERY, {
  options: ({ category }) => ({
    variables: { category }
  })
})(Home)
```

This will force parent component to re-render Home with new props and call query again with new variable for categoryId

Comment: Is it not possible alone by using the new `Query` component which is now there in `react-apollo` ?

Comment: @Mozak basically it doesn't matter if you wrap Home inside HoC component from 2.0, or use Query inside the render , concept of parent re-rendering remains same.

Comment: Yes, I used the way you suggest and it's working. Thanks.